# I'm writing a systemd timer. What value should I use for WantedBy?

Tags: systemd-timer

In various examples, I have seen all of these different choices suggested:

- WantedBy=timers.target
- WantedBy=multi-user.target
- WantedBy=basic.target
- WantedBy=default.target
- WantedBy=mytimer.target (custom user-defined name)

However, in the examples I have found, no further explanation is offered.

The following pages also don't offer any explanation of WantedBy:

- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html
- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html

I want to understand one simple* method I can use when needed to write a systemd timer instead of a cron job.

* *Setting up a cron job is 1 line. Systemd timers involve writing two files and running one or two systemctl commands. But that fact alone is not necessarily what makes systemd timers harder than cron in my experience -- it's the multitude of options and the (seeming) lack of clear documentation with simple examples that are fully explained.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the simple use case, use `WantedBy=timers.target`. See [`man systemd.special`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html):

> `timers.target`
>
> A special target unit that sets up all timer units (see
>   [systemd.timer(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#) for details) that shall be active after boot.
>
> It is recommended that timer units installed by applications get
>   pulled in via `Wants=` dependencies from this unit. This is best
>   configured via `WantedBy=timers.target` in the timer unit's
>   "`[Install]`" section.

Timers get a dependency of `Before=timers.target` by default. And, if you check [`man bootup`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html#), you'll see that `basic.target` pulls in `timers.target` as a dependency. So I think `WantedBy=basic.target` would appear to work OK for most cases (same for `default.target`, which is usually `multi-user.target` or `graphical.target`, both of which come after `basic.target`). But:

> `timers.target` is pulled-in by `basic.target` asynchronously. This
>   allows timers units to depend on services which become only available
>   later in boot.

So a more complicated timer that depends on some other service unit would be better off depending on `timers.target` rather than any of the others.